# Can an LLC be a non-profit 501c3? And can a for-profit LLC accept donations via patreon or kickstarter?

Tags: united-states, non-profit

Can an LLC be a non-profits? Or are LLC's by definition for-profit organizations? If the former, how would that designation be reached?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[An LLC can obtain a 501(c)(3) designation](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-tege/eotopicb01.pdf), but all its members/owners must also be 501(c)(3) non-profits.

So if Red Cross and Habitat for Humanity and Goodwill got together to start an LLC, that LLC could obtain a 501(c)(3) designation. If a human person is a member of an LLC, that LLC cannot obtain a 501(c)(3) designation.

I don't think there's any reason a for-profit LLC could not accept donations from Patreon or Kickstarter, but those donations would generally be treated as income, the same as money received in exchange for goods.

Comment: Now I'm imagining the NRA and the Brady Center forming an LLC together :)